# Finding names of all functions in program

Tags: c#

I was wondering how can I find all the names of functions that are in the program?
Any built in method for this?
Or any hint to how can I find?
*stack trace* or something like that?

Comment: With or without source code available?

Comment: Just for interest or do you have a real requirement?

Comment: no no just for interest , i mean just return all function names in rich text box when button clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var allMethods = typeof(AnyClass).Assembly
                                 .GetTypes()
                                 .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods());

var allMethodNames = allMethods.Select(method => method.Name);


Console.WriteLine( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allMethodNames) );
```

In order to inspect many assemblies, use next code:

```
Assembly[] assembliesToInspect = {
                                    typeof(AnyClass).Assembly, 
                                    typeof(ClassFromAnotherAssembly).Assembly
                                 };

var allMethods = assembliesToInspect.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods());
```

Comment: Actually it's `GetMethods().Select(m => m.FullName)`, because he was asking for a collection of names. Edit: lol, you just updated your post :)

Comment: yes, I'm sorry. That's `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: it returnsSystem.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Reflection.MethodInfo,System.String]

Comment: no method names returned

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to open your program or dll and enumerate all types and for each type enumerate all their public methods.